# why google map not load in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am following the the steps given in this link 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
I am getting error after load can you tell me where I wrong ? I already generate  key ?
fiddle
 http://jsfiddle.net/p3kcztvb/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map-canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATC35pv00Ga3hRxP4t5W7NtM9as48PGVQs">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following error explain itself.

```
"provided key is not a valid Google API Key,"
```

Generate correct key

```
To create your API key:

    Visit the APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console and log in with your Google Account.
    Click the Services link from the left-hand menu.
    Activate the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 service.
    Click the API Access link from the left-hand menu. Your API key is available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Maps API applications use the Key for browser apps.
```

[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key)

[image: pic here]

Markup Code as follow:-

```
// Adds a marker with popup window information
  var marker1Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.65654,-106);
  var contentString1 = 'I love New Mexico! <a href="http://www.newmexico.org">More</a> about the Land of Enchantment';
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString1
  });
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: marker1Latlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'New Mexico'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker1);
  });
//End of Add Marker code
```

Comment: how we generate that ?>can you please generate one

Comment: For that you have to use ur Gmail account. @kanikamittal

Comment: thanks for answering I am able to add google map http://jsfiddle.net/ebgpvfh0/1/.how to add markup in that

Comment: Added markup code. You have to modified accordingly. @kanikamittal

Answer (score 1):

Hi Kanika in Fiddle it seems like the API key you are using is not a valid key. You might need to regenerate the API key for Google Maps API Engine from your Google Console.

Comment: how we generate that key cazn you please give example on fiddle

Comment: you login to https://console.developers.google.com using your google credentials and then go to APIs & Auth on left handside and select credentials. And it will show all the keys on right side. Just follow the steps its easy Or follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiD97hpkRdU

Comment: thanks for answering I am able to add google map http://jsfiddle.net/ebgpvfh0/1/.how to add markup in that

Answer (score 0):

Change this code lines - basically you don't need a api key in here

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATC35pv00Ga3hRxP4t5W7NtM9as48PGVQs">
    </script>
```

Replace with

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp">
    </script>
```

Comment: I am able to get but to add mark up  thanks for answering I am able to add google map http://jsfiddle.net/ebgpvfh0/1/.how to add markup in that